# Hot to show/hide a <div> by clicking <a> tag when JavaScript is disabled?

Tags: php, html, css

Use  tag to show/hide div when click when JavaScript is disabled. Tried adjusting following example [Show hide divs on click in HTML and CSS without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170781/show-hide-divs-on-click-in-html-and-css-without-jquery) but that doesn't seem to work.

From this question [How to detect if JavaScript is disabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled) i assumed that there isn't a convenient way to check if JS is disabled like:

```
if(JS is disabled){
     // show <a> tag that words with jQuery to display div
} else {
    // show label to show/hide div onclick
}
```

Any ideas will be welcomed.

**Question** How to make "a" tag to show a mini login form stored in "div" when JavaScript is disabled. Because when it's enabled it ?

Below is coresponding code of tag "a" and "div".

```
<ul class="nav nav-bar pull-right" >
<li class="dropdown" id="menuLogin">

<a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" for="_1" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navLogin">Login</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding-left:17px; left:-70px; width:200px;">
    <?php 
        $form_sm = $this->form_sm;
        $form_sm->prepare();
        echo $this->form()->openTag($form_sm);
    ?>

    <dl class="form">
    <dd><?php
            echo $this->formElement($form_sm->get('email'));
            echo $this->formElementErrors($form_sm->get('email'));
        ?></dd>
    <dd><?php
            echo $this->formElement($form_sm->get('password'));
            echo $this->formElementErrors($form_sm->get('password'));
        ?></dd>
    <li class="divider" style="width:78%"></li>
    <dd><?php
            echo $this->formElement($form_sm->get('send'));
            echo $this->formElementErrors($form_sm->get('send'));
        ?></dd>
   <?php echo $this->form()->closeTag() ?>      
</div>

</li>
</ul>
```

It uses a Bootstrap3 and Zend Framework components and by clicking "a" tag following line

```
<li class="dropdown" id="menuLogin">
```

change to

```
<li class="dropdown open" id="menuLogin">
```

Comment: This might be one of those cases where you have to rethink your decision to have a div hide. I don't think disabling javascript is something people do too much anymore.

Comment: Do you have a login or is this for a no-login site?

Comment: You can use checkbox hack it is css's click function in my way. http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/

Comment: Easily done with php if you have a login...let me know

Comment: If you've disabled Javascript, your next best bet would be to use PHP to determine whether to hide or show it - you'll have to reload the page though.

Comment: I would look for a solution that would have the same html for both cases; I don't see why it should be different and if you really need it, you can use javascript to manipulate the DOM after it has been loaded.

Comment: Agreed @C Bauer....so much more effort when user has no JS, but these users are definitely in the very tiny minority. As developers, should we roughly double our design effort for the 1 user in 5000 (or whatever number it is)? I say no

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect if JavaScript is disabled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/121203/how-to-detect-if-javascript-is-disabled)

Comment: @ The One and Only ChemistryBlob div that i want to show/hide is a small login form.

Comment: I know that there aren't a lot of people who doesn't use JS but this option should also be provided unfortunatelly.

Comment: @ The One and Only if you have an example please write it down.

Answer (score 0):

You can use checkbox hack to do it. Since it is pure CSS there are some limitations. The elements you want to hide have to be siblings or children of the label you will use so you can select them when you get the `:checked` status. You can't go up to a element's parent in CSS.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/carloscalla/msaccf9w/

HTML:

```
<label class="hide_action" for="chk1">Action toggle</label>
<input id="chk1" type="checkbox" />
<div>Sibling div</div>
```

CSS:

```
.hide_action{
  display:block;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.hide_action + input{ /* or #chk1 */
  display:none;
}
.hide_action + input + *{ /* or #chk1 (selector for what you want to hide) */
  display:none;
}
.hide_action + input:checked + *{ /* or #chk1:checked (selector for what you want to hide) */
  display:block;
}
```

You can not go up a parent and hide other element since you won't be able to get a selector for it. You can go down in children or siblings.

In this example I use `+ input` to select the adyacent input to the `label` if you don't want them to be together you can identify it by an id as in the CSS comments.