# Show/Hide login form when JavaScript is disabled

Tags: php, html, css

I am having a small login form and want to display it in case JavaScript is disabled. Form has similar structure :

```
<a ...href="#"...>Login</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding-left:17px; left:-70px; width:200px;">
<form action="/login/" method="post" ....>
.... form components ....
</form></div>
```

div with class "dropdown-menu" has display:none initial. And when click "a" tag or hover it should change to display:block. Found simillar issue here [Show hide divs on click in HTML and CSS without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170781/show-hide-divs-on-click-in-html-and-css-without-jquery) but there are solution only for **label** and using **tabindex and :focus**.

**Done** Thanks to @Florian i've fixxed my problem. Here is code if someone is interested.

in .html file

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" style="display:none" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" id="navLogin">Login</a>

<input type='checkbox' style='display: none' id=cb>
<label class="dropdown-toggle" id="labelLogin" for=cb>Login</label>

<div class="dropdown-menu" style="padding-left:17px; left:-70px; width:200px;">
    <form ...... >
         ... Form Components...
    </form>
</div>
```

in .css file

```
input:checked + label + div { display: block; }
label {position: relative;

padding: 10px 15px;
color:#428bca;
}
```

And in .js File

```
$('#navLogin').removeAttr('style');
$('#labelLogin').css('display', 'none');
```

Following code will show "a" tag when JavaScript is enabled and will show only label when it's disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something that you can toggle. Beside javascript the only way to change some state in a html page is the checkbox element. With some tricks this can be used to show/hide other elements.

Have a look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/gSPqX/1/ (Not created by myself). It is a bit simpler than the solution you linked and also uses a div.

Basically the trick is to use the + Operator in the css code which selects next sibling element.

```
input:checked + label + div { display: none; }
```

(Taken from the fiddle)

So you have three elements, the checkbox-input, the label and the div. The checkbox is used to save the current state, the label is used to have a larger clickable area and the div contains the actual data.

Comment: and should i hide "a" tag when JS is disabled and show input and label ?

Comment: If you are just talking about the appearance, you can style the label tag and also add the hover effect, so that there is no visual difference. Have a look at the forked fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/sp4ot4p2/

Comment: When clickng on "a" tag it does nothing.

Comment: I edited the post and updated the link, make sure you use the current version (no a-tag included anymore)

Answer (score 0):

Use `noscript` like this:

```
 <noscript>
    <style>
       #noscript{display:none !important;}
       #container{display:none;}
    </style>
 </noscript>
```

Comment: This will make div show/hide when clicking "a" tag?