# Show Hide Div On Click Making Label Disappear HTML/CSS Only

Tags: show-hide

I think this is going to be a pretty simple question for most of you.

I am using this code I found here on a previous question asked awhile ago:

Here is the code:
http://jsbin.com/Amejum/2/edit?html,css,output

Here is the question:
[Show hide divs on click in HTML and CSS without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170781/show-hide-divs-on-click-in-html-and-css-without-jquery)

The code works great. I just wanted to be able to do one more thing, not sure if it is possible. Is there a way using only HTML and CSS only to make the label text (in the example it is "Collapse 1") disappear after being clicked? Or changing its color after being clicked?

Thank You.