# How to show one element when click on the another element with css?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've used this css code for showing the element when click on the  search id tag. This is possible with jquery but I want to do this with css only. Please advise.

```
   #open_search:active #search{
    display: block;
    transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}
```

html

```
<div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span2 language pull-right">
                <div class="language-object">
</div>
            </div>
            <span id="open_search" class=" btn glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            <div id="search" class="span3 pull-left">
                <span id="dnn_dnnSearch_ClassicSearch">
    <span class="searchInputContainer" data-moreresults="مشاهده نتایج بیشتر" data-noresult="نتیجه‌ای یافت نشد">
        <input name="dnn$dnnSearch$txtSearch" maxlength="255" size="20" id="dnn_dnnSearch_txtSearch" class="NormalTextBox" autocomplete="off" placeholder="جستجو..." type="text">
        <a class="dnnSearchBoxClearText"></a>
    </span>
    <a id="dnn_dnnSearch_cmdSearch" class="SearchButton pull-left" href="javascript:__doPostBack('dnn$dnnSearch$cmdSearch','')">Search</a>
</span>
                <span id="close_search" class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-remove "></span>
            </div>
            <div id="login" class="span5  pull-left">

<div id="dnn_dnnLogin_loginGroup" class="registerGroup">
    <a id="dnn_dnnLogin_enhancedLoginLink" title="ورود" class="LoginLink" rel="nofollow" onclick="this.disabled=true;" href="http://localhost/dnn_test/Login?returnurl=%2fdnn_test%2fskin2">&nbsp;ورود&nbsp;</a>
</div>
<div id="dnn_dnnUser_registerGroup" class="registerGroup">
    <ul class="buttonGroup">
        <li class="userDisplayName list-inline">
            <a id="dnn_dnnUser_enhancedRegisterLink" title="ثبت‌نام" rel="nofollow" href="http://localhost/dnn_test/Register?returnurl=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%2fdnn_test%2fskin2">&nbsp;ثبت‌نام</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

If it is not possible with css, then please help to do this with jquery.

Comment: Change `#open_search:active #search` to  `#open_search:active + #search`

Comment: This is right. but this worked when click on the #open_search . I want after click on the   #open_search it show always

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: It is not possible by pure css to add class and remove class. You have to use javascript or jquery.

Comment: This would help you. [show hide element with css only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170781/show-hide-divs-on-click-in-html-and-css-without-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Css:

```
#search {
    display: none;
    transition: all 100ms ease-in-out;
}

#search.active {
    display: block;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
   $("#open_search").click(function(){
       $("#search").toggleClass("active");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

another nice thing is to use labels and checkboxes

```
<label for="openContent">Toggle Content</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="openContent" style="display:none;" />
<div id="myContent">Here!</div>
```

and CSS

```
<style>
    #openContent + #myContent {
        display:none;
    }

    #openContent:checked + #myContent {
        display:block;
    }
</style>
```

see in [jsFidlde](https://jsfiddle.net/xwf5j9g9/)