# Tabs with css3, changing style on click

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use [this recepee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170781/show-hide-divs-on-click-in-html-and-css-without-jquery) to implement tabs without using JS or JQuery, pure CSS, but I am stuck.
The goal is to show different content on click on some label, and change the label style.
Now it shows labels as I want, but content of each div somehow shown over the label, not under. Also, I cannot make it change style. Could anybody help? Thanks. Sorry if the question looks stupid - I am just starting with html.

Now it is like that:[image]

```
<div id="menu">
    <label class="collapse" for="1">tab1</label> <input id="1" name="r" type="radio" />
    <div>111111111111111111111</div>
    <label class="collapse" for="2">tab2</label> <input id="2" name="r" type="radio"/>
    <div>2222222222222222222222</div>
    <label class="collapse" for="3">tab3</label> <input id="3" name="r" type="radio" />
    <div>333333333333333333333</div>
</div>
```

my css:

```
    #menu {
        padding-left: 20px;
    }

    #menu label {
        height: 30px;
        background-color: #d1ecee;
        width: 75px;
        color: #2cb674;
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        margin-left: 2px;
    display:block;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }

    #menu label:before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        left: -20px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-top: 30px solid #d1ecee;
        border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    display:block;
    }

    #menu label:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        right: -20px;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-bottom: 30px solid #d1ecee;
        border-right: 20px solid transparent;

    }

#menu input {
    display: none !important;
}

#menu input+* {
    display: none !important;
}
#menu input:checked+* {
    display: block !important;
}

#menu input:checked+label {
    background-color: #2cb674;
    color: white;
}

#menu input:checked+label:before {
    border-top: 30px solid #2cb674;
}

#menu input:checked+label:after {
    border-bottom: 30px solid #2cb674;
}
```

UPDATE:

this is the picture I have now due to absolute positioning of target div
[image]

Comment: why you use menu + input in first place? hmm

Comment: @SzymonDziewoński It seems it doesn't affect the result. Also I added another part of css I missed before.

Comment: For starters your rules with `#menu +input` will never work. `+` tells CSS to find a sibling. However your inputs are children of #menu, not it's siblings.

Comment: Also your `input:checked label` rules will not work since label is a sibling to input, but this is telling CSS to find a label that is a child of input

Comment: @tbernard I edited, please see, still doesn't work as needed

Comment: you could have a look at the `:focus` psuedo selector too, used in conjunction with `tabindex` in the HTML it can give a selected effect, however, it's more for visual effect rather than interactive elements - there's a few questions on here somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with your sibling selectors. the `+` sign should select the next sibling element in your HTML, refer to [30 CSS selectors you should know](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

A more elegant way is to:

1. hide your radio buttons with `opacity` and `absolute` positioning
2. make the tab content containers `absolute` positioned to keep them below tab buttons
3. show the tab content whose radio button is checked
4. re-arranage the html so the the order is `input`, `label` then `div`

## HTML

```
<div id="menu">

    <!-- Selected by default -->

    <input id="1" name="r" type="radio" checked/>
    <label class="collapse" for="1">tab1</label>
    <div>111111111111111111111</div>

    <input id="2" name="r" type="radio"/>
    <label class="collapse" for="2">tab2</label>
    <div>2222222222222222222222</div>

    <input id="3" name="r" type="radio" />
    <label class="collapse" for="3">tab3</label>
    <div>333333333333333333333</div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
#menu {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
#menu label {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #d1ecee;
    width: 75px;
    color: #2cb674;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 2px;
    display:block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
#menu label:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: -20px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 30px solid #d1ecee;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    display:block;
}
#menu label:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: -20px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom: 30px solid #d1ecee;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
}
#menu input:checked + label {
    background-color: #2cb674;
    color: white;
}
#menu input:checked + label:before {
    border-top: 30px solid #2cb674;
}

#menu input:checked + label:after {
    border-bottom: 30px solid #2cb674;
}

/* Hide radio buttons */
#menu input[type=radio]{
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    left:-200%;
}

/* Hide all tab divs and keep them below the tab buttons */
#menu > div {
    display:none;
    top:5em;
    position:absolute;
    max-width:100%;
}

/* Show the tab whose sibling radio button is checked */
#menu input:checked + label + div{
    display:block;
}
```

[image: tabs in CSS]

This should work just fine

Comment: That's awesome. I tried to put label after input according to some principles, but was still fiddling around. Thanks a lot, I appreciate your help. I learned a lot also.

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem I faced: it works if it is the only element on the page, but if I put it inside some div surrounded by other divs, tabs change their styles ok, but related divs are shown in absolute position somewhere on top, covering all other content. If I remove position:absolute; from #menu > div, it completely disrupts the design (( Could you check please? Thanks. Just for the case: content divs are for showing lists of data, so they can be of any size.

Comment: could you take a screenshot so I can see what's happening? The reason I used absolute positioning is so that all the divs can stay below the tabs, like a stack of cards

Comment: yes, please check in my updated question.