# Hide element based on NavBar?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a way to hide/show elements based on the bootstrap NavBar selection without additional JS or jQuery?

I have a NavBar with ("T1", "T2", "T3").
The page has three tables (T1, T2, T3).
When "T1" is pressed in the NavBar, I would like to hide T2 and T3, etc..

Comment: If you want interactivity on a webpage, you need a language to describe your interactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to hide/show elements based on the bootstrap NavBar selection **without additional JS or jQuery**?

#### Kind of

You can use Bootstrap's [collapse](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/) plugin to emulate an accordion for your tables. The collapse plugin works by using a few CSS classes and data attributes to show and hide content.

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Expand/collapse
</a>
<div id="collapseExample" class="collapse">
    Here's the content you want to expand/collapse.
</div>
```

You can specify a `data-parent` attribute on the collapsible content to achieve an accordion-like behavior (i.e., only one section is visible at a time). Bootstrap's documentation shows how to create an [accordion](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/collapse/#accordion-example) using the `data-parent` attribute.

I put together a snippet below that looks similar to what you've described in your question. You can also view the [example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LXpLaJ?editors=1000).

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light mb-4">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Site</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" id="headingOne" href="#collapseOne" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">Table 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" id="headingTwo" href="#collapseTwo" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">Table 2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" id="headingThree" href="#collapseThree" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">Table 3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div id="accordionExample">
  <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
    <h2>Table 1</h2>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Numbers</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>3</th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
    <h2>Table 2</h2>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">More numbers</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>3</th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
    <h2>Table 3</h2>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Even more numbers</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>3</th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Caveat

The behavior may not be exactly what you want. If that's the case, then you'll probably have to resort to using JS to solve this problem. There are definitely [other examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170781/show-hide-divs-on-click-in-html-and-css-without-jquery) of showing and hiding content without JS, but it may be difficult to achieve what you're looking for without it.