# Multiple Hyperlink contents targetted to display in one html file

Tags: html, css

I have 2 hyperlinks.
I am aiming to target every hyperlink content to be displayed in a single page "result.html"

Example:
Many to one -> Many hyper links content to one <.html> page

```
click hyper link1:  ------> hyper link1's content in <result.html>
                                                                                      
click hyper link2:  ------> hyper link2's content in <result.html>
```

I tried using **iframe**, but no luck.

Could you please suggest where I went wrong.

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to acheive? Do you have an example of the code you've already tried.

Comment: Hello @learningtoanimate , Say I have 2 hyperlinks, a and b. And I have a result.html page.
When I click on a, a's content should be displayed in result.html
When I click on b, b's content should be displayed in result.html

What I Tried: 
<iframe src="page1.html" name="iframe_a" title="Iframe trial1"></iframe>

<p><a href="url" target="iframe_a">result</a></p>

Comment: Update your question with the code for each location, this may be something you need to use PHP for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that you have two anchor elements in the same page `result.html`

`<a href="">Go To A Content</a>`

`<a href="">Go To B Content</a>`

And you need to click on `Go To A Content` to jump to a `<div>` element with content A and click on `Go To B Content` to jump to a `<div>` element with content B.

1. Give each `<div>` element an `id=""`

`<div id="content_a"> .... </div>`

`<div id="content_b"> .... </div>`

2. Use this id in each corresponding anchor element as follows:

`<a href="#content_a">Go To A Content</a>`

`<a href="#content_b">Go To B Content</a>`

This should do the mission.

I hope this is informative and have a happy code.

Comment: Hello @Ahmed, 
Although the given solution works for same page, when i will have to invoke specific div only from different .html page, it does not work. It displays all the divisions in the target page. Could you please advice

Comment: inside the `href=""` attribute just before the hashtag `href="#"` you can add the link of the page you want to use this anchor tag to jump into it. `<a href="../some/another/html/page/link#content_a">Go To A Content</a>` This will be it. Now you can go to the .html page with the link `../some/another/html/page/link` inside this page you have to name an element with `id="content_a"` so when you click on `Go To A Content` you jump to that page and jump also to that element inside of it

Comment: Hi @Ahmed, Yes, I did the same. But No Luck. 
doc1:{ <li><a href="connection.html#content_a">link1</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="connection.html#content_b" >link2 </a></li>}
 connection.html: {<div id="content_a">
            <object type="text/html" data="path_to_file1.html">
            </object>
        </div>} {<div id="content_b">
            <object type="text/html" data="path_to_file2.html"></object></div> }                     Both the divs are getting displayed, when i click on link 1

Answer (score 1):

What about using a parameter?
like this :

```
http://localhost/result.html?show=contentA
  
http://localhost/result.html?show=contentB
```

or use jquery to change element
So instead of loading a new page the link is change the element you want..

On below sample I will change the image on a webpage :

```
<img id="thechange" src="/images/test1.jpg"/>
```

the link is like this :

```
<button onclick="change('Test2.jpg')" value="Change2"/>
<button onclick="change('Test3.jpg')" value="Change3"/>
<button onclick="change('Test1.jpg')" value="Change1"/>
```

The script is like below :

```
<script>
function change(imageName)
{
  $("#thechange").attr("src","/images/"+imageName)
}
</script>
```

Third option : Using pure css
(copying the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170781/show-hide-divs-on-click-in-html-and-css-without-jquery)

Try using css like this :

```
.collapse{
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  background: #cdf;
}
.collapse + input{
  display: none; /* hide the checkboxes */
}
.collapse + input + div{
  display:none;
}
.collapse + input:checked + div{
  display:block;
}
```

Html part :

```
<label class="collapse" for="_1">Collapse 1</label>
<input id="_1" type="checkbox"> 
<div>Content 1</div>

<label class="collapse" for="_2">Collapse 2</label>
<input id="_2" type="checkbox">
<div>Content 2</div>
```

Hope this is what you need

Comment: Hi, @Ahmad. Yes your solution will work with javascript. I am trying to cover this requirement only using html. Can I use iframe in the same place ?

Comment: Please check my third option

Comment: Actually, I don't like how iframe show scrolling. 
So what about using div like my sample?